# Django how redirect to other site by post query string

Tags: django, django-views

How can I redirect from first site to second site.

Second site have form:

```
<form action="http://example.com/authAs" method="POST">
    <input id="login" type="text" name="login"></td>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password"></td>
    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

I want to authenticate the user at the first site and redirect it to a second site already authorized by POST request

How can I do it?

I have tried do it:

```
import urllib2,urllib
post_data = [('login', login), ('password', password)]
result = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/authAs', urllib.urlencode(post_data))
content = result.read()
```

But how redirect user to authorized page on second site?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to redirect through POST, if you want the client to post to another site the only option is to use javascript to make a browser based redirection.

Instead of redirecting to example site, you can redirect to a local page with the form html and add this JS:

```
document.forms['form_id'].submit();
```

Note that the client will see the page for a few seconds before redirection and it won't work if JS is not enabled.